# How can I make CrystalReportViewer not use flash?

Tags: java, flash, jsp, crystal-reports

I have written a .jsp file that uses CrystalReportViewer and Java.  This works fine for IE and Chrome but not Firefox.  This file also doesn't work with most mobile devices, i.e iPhone.  The main cause of all these issues is the parameter selection is flash.  This flash selection window shows when it wants too.

Is there any way around this?  I dont want it to use flash. Could I change it to use jQuery?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to just redesign the report to NOT use flash.  Could this be an Xcelcius object or similar plugin?  Are you inserting a whole report of just a report (flash) object.  AFAICT, a flash object is "sealed".  If you know the names/type/format of the parameters, it MIGHT be possible to set those in code, but if it were, if might get superceeded by the flash object on processing.  Even if it were, I don't know how you would conditionally override the flash (show Flash when IE available but not when FF).

So I guess I'm back the my first thought... fix the report so it doesn't use Flash.

Comment: Yes that is the ideal solution, but I don't have any control over the embedded flash object.  The flash object automatically get generated by the Java CrystalReportViewer class.  I want to set away from the Java CrystalReportViewer class all together.    All I want to do is view a .rpt file in a browser.  Is there anyway to do this without the CrystalReportViewer?  Thank you so much!